# Communication between computer with Labview and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, communication

I would like to use a computer with Labview to send commands to a Raspberry Pi, for the moment I am just trying to get a LED to blink.

What would be the best way to proceed ?

I have thought of two ways of doing this:

- Either send a ssh command via labview to the Pi asking it to run `python led_blink.py`.
- Or have a program running on the Pi that monitors a configuration file, and once the file contains `blink_led = True` it starts blinking.

Is there a better way to order the Raspberry Pi to run some simple and more complex commands ?

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: The answer may depend on what way you consider "the best". What's wrong with sending an SSH command?

Comment: Yet another way is to let LabView send text commands via UART/serial interface, eg, 9,600 baud, 8N1. So Labview sends command "AT", Rpi replies "OK". Lebview says "BLINK LED 2 , 3 TIMES", Rpi would blink LED accordingly.  Of course LabView can also send complicated commands, such as "RUN PROGRAM XYZ"

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev For this application "best" would mean reliable (not necessarily fast). I got a simple test working with SSH but I was wondering what was the more traditional way to tell a Raspberry Pi to blink.

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for the indication I will look that up

Comment: Does that mean that your tests show that SSH is unreliable? And I'm not even going to ask what "traditional" means. In my experience, a traditional way of blinking a LED from LabView doesn't involve a Raspberry Pi at all.

Comment: @Anthony Lethuillier, you are welcome.  Your question is a bit open, so as I said, I am just brainstorming yet one more suggestion.  In brainstorming sessions, other members usually severely attack me, I mean my suggestion, with questions such as "What are the pros and cons", ... etc.  So perhaps I will list the things I usually used to defend my suggestion, / to continue, ...

Comment: So ssh works well, but labview by default has TCP communications enabled so that also seems to work quite well.